# Reference to part of the site using existing JavaScript animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to design a website. I decided to work with this [template](https://templatemo.com/tm-497-upper) from templatemo.

I am currently trying to add a reference to a specific part of the website (e.g. Contact) in the "normal text area". I tried to just add a href in the text, like this:

```
    Contact me via the <a href="#contact_form" >Contact Form</a>
```

This does not work properly. If I click on the reference, the whole layout is somehow messed up. I assume this is because the click on the link does not trigger the javascript function for the "changing the slide" properly.

**My question is now:**
How can I trigger the javascript functions, for "changing the slide" to a specific part of the page in regular text areas?
This animation is already implemented and works properly (e.g. it is triggered when clicking on the buttons in the navigation bar).   However, I have no clue how to use the same animation for jumping to a part of the page outside of the navigation bar.

I hope you understand my problem.
Thank you in advance for your support!

Comment: So `<a href="#contact_form" >` is not working? Is there an element in the page with `id` set to `contact-form`?

Comment: You might need to disable the default action or prevent it from getting triggered. Anyhow needs more reproducible details.

Comment: The reference is working, but if I click on it, there are two problems: 
1. The page does not "animate" to the new slide, it just reloads the page to that slide. 
2. Depending on where I put the id of the "contact_form" in the code, the reloaded page looks messed up. For instance only "half" of the new slide is shown. 

I think working only with an id and href does not really work, since the page is then not reloaded via the javascript. What I need is some sort of code that trigger the javascript animation as it is triggered when clicking on a button in the navigation bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, you would have to modify the page contents in the respective location in the HTML file. The way this file is constructed is that you have a `ul` list with `li` elements that indicate each page, and each `li` element is given a numerical value that represents its position in the list (e.g. 1, 2, 3, ...). Make sure to edit and add any new pages in this part of the markup. If you want to adjust or trigger any page transitions, edit the `data-no` value in the `<a>` tag in `#tmNavbar` to the position of the page in the list.

If you want to trigger the transition from elsewhere in the website, I would recommend just clicking on the respective nav-item using Javascript. For example,

```
$('.nav-item').get(i).click() /* i is the data-no value` */
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! How can I embedd this Code in the regular text, so that the specific word ist highlighted? (as in : <a href="#contact_form" >Contact Form</a>")?

Comment: I found a solution to embedd it in the text: 
`Contact me via the <a id="myLink" href="#" onclick="$('.nav-item').get(5).click()">contact form</a>`

This triggers the animation :-) Maybe one last question: 
What is the purpose of the id="myLink"?

Comment: I don't see why the id would be necessary.